# Function behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
  var dayName = function() {
  var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
               "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return function(number) {
    return names[number];
  };
}();

console.log(dayName(1));
o/p->Monday
```

When the same code is executed without the paranthesis'()' at the end in the dayName variable O/P is different..What is the reason?

Comment: when you run `dayName(1)` you are calling the function dayName with the input argument `1`. the result will be returned and printed. where as if you just print `dayName` without the parentheses you are not calling the function but simply printing the variable dayName which is a function.

Comment: Well, of course there is a difference between calling a function and not calling it?!

Comment: As Bergi said. First you define a function var dayName. It is now merely defined, you didn't do anything with it yet. The parenthesis at the end is then dayName(), which is a function call.

Comment: Sorry ,I meant the parenthesis  in the function definition assigned to the dayName variable not the function call